# Is it safe for Mac not to sleep for over a month

Tags: startup, sleep-wake, gpu

My 17 Inch, Late 2011 MacbookPro has a problem with its discrete graphic card it boots with vertical pink stripes screen then switches to a gray screen where it remains stuck for a while and then automatically reboots.

I googled the problem and figured a workaround. I just need to wait for the gray screen where my mac gets stuck, close the lid and wrap my mac with a blanket until it overheats and auto-shutdowns. I immediately then turn-on the overheated mac which will make it boot with the integrated card, and problem solved! After I login I use gfxCardStatus to set the graphics to integrated only.

The problem is if I close the lid to sleep my mac at some point, it will never open again unless I redo the entire overheating process. I'm aware Apple recognized the problem recently and is now offering free fixes to it but where I'm living right now there's only Apple recognized providers but no official Apple store. The Apple service provider representative told me that they will have to send my Mac abroad to fix it and that can take over a month which is too long for me... I have a project going on and I have to wrap it up before mid May.

My Mac works perfectly with the integrated card, and I'm thinking to keep it awake for about month until I finish my project then schedule a proper repair with AppleCare, which sounds safer than overheating my Mac every time I boot or wake my mac. My question is: is it too bad for my Mac to stay awake for over a month?

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but, anecdotally - my Mac has been running 24/7 since 2008, never sleeping & only ever rebooting/shutting down for OS updates/hardware clean etc. No issues so far.

Comment: @Tetsujin that pretty much answers my question actually. I'll just wait to see if anybody else had a different experience not sleeping their Mac for a while then check your comment (if you make it an answer) . Thanks!

Comment: I can throw it into an answer but it just felt a bit glib, & not much else I could do to flesh it out ;-)

Comment: Totally agree with **Tetsujin**, the only time my machines get shutdown or restarted are for updates and hardware changes. As an aside to this, just out of curiosity one day last year I ran the **uptime** command via ARD on all the tutors' MacBooks at our campus, and the record holder had an uptime of 187 days. As she was a non-technical staff member I went to check everything was running ok, and sure enough it was - apart from the rather large queue of Apple updates she persistently ignored as she "didn't have time for that sort of thing".

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly I never shutdown my computer too unless for updates but I do put it asleep. Do you keep your Mac awake all the time? you don't close the lid?

Comment: I *occasionally* close the lid on my main MacBook at home but it's generally busy downloading something or other, and it rarely goes anywhere - I do let the display sleep though and I'll cycle the battery once a week to keep it healthy. Apart from a couple of holidays that's pretty much how it's been for the last three years...

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly ok, thank you for the feedback... I wish I could up-vote but I got no reputations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't fix your issue, but, anecdotally…

My Mac has been running 24/7 since 2008, never sleeping & only ever rebooting/shutting down for OS updates/hardware clean etc.

No issues so far.

So I'd say, yes, it's perfectly safe to leave it awake, so long as it has adequate cooling.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer @Tetsujin, I'll check your answer by the end of the day if I get no different opinion.